# Problems to upload data into PostGIS using Python

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas

good morning!

I'm doing an exercise that consists in download data from Open Street Map, do some ETL stuffs and upload it into a PostGIS database. The download and ETL worked well, but I'm having problems to upload my data into a table using to_postgis or to_sql.

The problem is that I can upload data using if_exists='replace', but when I tried to update the table using if_exists='append' it doesn't work. This function only works when the table doesn't exist in my database, so running using append the function will create the table and insert the data there, but if I run again to add more data it will not work anymore :(

I will put here the code that I'm using, sorry if is a messy but I'm a beginner hehe

this is my library, maybe have more things than I need

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd, json
import requests
import os
import json
import osmnx as osm
import sqlalchemy as sql
import shapely
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
```

My connection parameters and other constants

```
USERNAME = 'postgres'
PASSWORD = 'postgres'
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5433
DB = 'programming_project'
AMENITY_LIST_POLYGON = ["hospital",'school','university']

LINK_DB = sql.create_engine(f"postgresql://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST}:{PORT}/{DB}")
```

Here some ETL that I'm doing in Open Street Map data, I'm taking some data from Lisbon, tag: amenity and values into this list AMENITY_LIST_POLYGON

```
# ETL amenities polygon

#download facilities from OSM
fac_amenities_pol= osm.geometries_from_place("Lisbon",tags={"amenity":AMENITY_LIST_POLYGON})

#to filter the columns that we want
fac_amenities_pol=fac_amenities_pol[['geometry','amenity','name','addr:postcode','addr:street','email','website','addr:housenumber','phone','contact:phone','contact:email','contact:website']].reset_index()
fac_amenities_pol['email'] = fac_amenities_pol['email'].fillna(fac_amenities_pol.pop('contact:email'))
fac_amenities_pol['phone'] = fac_amenities_pol['phone'].fillna(fac_amenities_pol.pop('contact:phone'))
fac_amenities_pol['website'] = fac_amenities_pol['website'].fillna(fac_amenities_pol.pop('contact:website'))


#to concatenate the address
fac_amenities_pol['address']=fac_amenities_pol['addr:street']+', Nº '+fac_amenities_pol['addr:housenumber']+' - Postal Code: '+fac_amenities_pol['addr:postcode']
fac_amenities_pol= fac_amenities_pol.drop(columns=['addr:street','addr:housenumber','addr:postcode'])

# Rename columns to match the database model
fac_amenities_pol = fac_amenities_pol.rename(columns={
        "addr:street":"address",
        "addr:postcode":"postal_cod",
        "amenity":"facility",
        "phone":"phone_number"})
        
#to filter only the geometry that we want
fac_amenities_pol=fac_amenities_pol.query("element_type != 'node'")

fac_amenities_pol.rename_geometry('geom',inplace=True)
```

Here starts my problem.

```
#to insert the data into database
fac_amenities_pol.to_postgis("facilities",LINK_DB,if_exists='append', index=False, dtype={'geom': Geometry(geometry_type='POLYGON', srid= 4326)})
```

Using to_postgis, the error that appears is

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\conta\miniconda3\envs\lisbon_engine\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1410, in Connection.execute(self, statement, parameters, execution_options)
   1409 try:
-> 1410     meth = statement._execute_on_connection
   1411 except AttributeError as err:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_execute_on_connection'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ObjectNotExecutableError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[159], line 2
      1 #to insert the data into database
----> 2 fac_amenities_pol.to_postgis("facilities11",LINK_DB,if_exists='append', index=False, dtype={'geom': Geometry(geometry_type='POLYGON', srid= 4326)})

File c:\Users\conta\miniconda3\envs\lisbon_engine\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py:1931, in GeoDataFrame.to_postgis(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
   1871 def to_postgis(
   1872     self,
   1873     name,
   (...)
   1880     dtype=None,
   1881 ):
   1882     """
   1883     Upload GeoDataFrame into PostGIS database.
...
   1416         distilled_parameters,
   1417         execution_options or NO_OPTIONS,
   1418     )

ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: "SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'facilities11', 'geom');"
```

Using to_sql the error is different, but I couldn't find a solution for anyone of them.

```
fac_amenities_pol.to_sql("facilities",LINK_DB, if_exists='append', index=False,dtype={'geom': Geometry('POLYGON', srid=4326)})
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\conta\miniconda3\envs\lisbon_engine\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:2100, in Connection._exec_insertmany_context(self, dialect, context)
   2099     else:
-> 2100         dialect.do_execute(cursor, sub_stmt, sub_params, context)
   2102 except BaseException as e:

File c:\Users\conta\miniconda3\envs\lisbon_engine\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py:747, in DefaultDialect.do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    746 def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 747     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Polygon'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[160], line 3
----> 3 fac_amenities_pol.to_sql("facilities",LINK_DB, if_exists='append', index=False,dtype={'geom': Geometry('POLYGON', srid=4326)})

File c:\Users\conta\miniconda3\envs\lisbon_engine\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:2987, in NDFrame.to_sql(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
   2830 """
   2831 Write records stored in a DataFrame to a SQL database.
   2832
```

I understood that to_sql doesn't recognize the geometry Polygon, but I also try with points or exploding the multipolygon into polygon but doesn't work. And to_postgis doesn't recognise the SRID, but as I said before, if the table doesn't exist it will create the table with the correct SRID (4326), but if I try to append new data will not work.

I really dont know what's happen, I tried a lot to search a solution here but looks like that no one had these problems before.

Comment: Can you print the column names of the final geodataframe that you want to upload.

Comment: You are appending to "facilities" table and in the next run you are appending it to "facilities11" table (that is what is shown in the stacktrace) are you sure you are appending to the same table?

Comment: darth baba yeah, it's the same table, because I changed the name inside the code to put here but I forgot to change in log, because I was trying a lot of tables different approaches, so I created lot of tables hehe

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in GeoPandas the issue can be found [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/2681). The suggested workaround is to downgrade to sqlalchemy<2.0.0. Actually it is caused because the run sqlalchemy is not using `sqlalchemy.text`